# Redirigir a vista mediante peticion URL ajax

Tags: jquery, laravel, ajax

tengo en mi vista un select y lo que necesito es que al seleccionar un item de ese select primero me redireccione a otra vista donde recibire un parametro que viene por la url que tengo en el ajax.

En las herramientas del navegador me retorna la vista pero en el front no hace la redireccion jeje...

la ruta (intente con post y get y en ambas es el mismo resultado):

```
Route::get('/reversa/filtro/ot/{num_ot}', [DespachoReversaController::class, 'getDespachoOT'])->name('reversa.busqueda.ot');
```

Este es el codigo del ajax (utilizando el evento change):

```
$('#num_ot').on('change', function(){
        var num_ot = $(this).val();
        $('#n').val('');
        $.ajax({
            url:"{{ url('reversa/filtro/ot') }}"+`/${num_ot}`,
            method:"get",
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(response){
                window.location.href = response.redirect;
            //console.log('El resultado es:', result);
                /* var opciones = '';
                var opciones = '<option value="">--Seleccione Técnico--</option>';
                result.tecnicos.forEach(element => {
                    opciones += `<option value="${element.id}">${element.nombre_primario} ${element.nombre_secundario} ${element.ape_pat} ${element.ape_mat}</option>`;
                });
                $("#tecnico_id").html(opciones)
                $("#tecnico_id").removeAttr('disabled'); */
            }
        })
    });
```

y en el controlador asi:

```
 public function getDespachoOT($num_ot){

        //return $num_ot;

        $despacho = Despacho::where('id',$num_ot)->first();
      
        return view('logistica.despacho.reversa.indexOT',compact('despacho'));

    }
```

Saludos a todos

Comment: ¿Por que tienes que hacer la solicitud por ajax? Puedes irte directamente desde el evento onchange, por otra parte, el controlador devuelve una vista y no variables que contenga `redirect`

Comment: Lo que pasa es que necesito que al hacer el filtro(es decir al seleccionar un valor del select) me lleve a la nueva vista y en esa vista recibir el parámetro del select para mostrar los datos según ese valor, o sea sería como hacer el submit de un form normal pero vía Ajax con redirección a la nueva vista

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando te envía la devolución en el ajax() window es un global por tanto seria asi

```
location.href = response.redirect;
```

debes asegurarte que response.redirect es la url a la cual quieres que tu codigo vaya

y deberias ponerun console.log() para verificar que tu evento se esta disparando en on() asi sabras si el error esta en el ajax() o en el propio disparador de tu evento

Comment: gracias me sirvio!